# Define a val later in Scala

Tags: scala, scope

I use this code to save an image uploaded by a form to DB:

```
  def saveImage(userIdSource: String) = Action.async(gridFSBodyParser(gridFS)) { request =>
    // here is the future file!
    val futureFile = request.body.files.head.ref
    // when the upload is complete, we add the article id to the file entry (in order to find the attachments of the article)

    val futureUpdate = for {
      file <- futureFile
      // here, the file is completely uploaded, so it is time to update the user
      updateResult <- {

        gridFS.files.update(
          BSONDocument("_id" -> file.id),
          BSONDocument("$set" -> BSONDocument("metadata" ->
            BSONDocument("user" -> BSONObjectID(userIdSource),
              "size" -> "original"))))

        val iterator = gridFS.enumerate(file).run(Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]())
        iterator.flatMap {
          bytes => {
            // Create resized image
            val enumerator: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.outputStream(
              out => {
                Image(bytes).bound(120, 120).writer(Format.JPEG).withCompression(90).write(out)
              }
            )

            val data = DefaultFileToSave(
              filename = file.filename,
              contentType = file.contentType,
              uploadDate = Some(DateTime.now().getMillis),
              metadata = file.metadata ++ BSONDocument(
                "user" -> BSONObjectID(userIdSource),
                "size" -> "thumb"
              )
            )

            Logger.warn(s"Saving resized image: [id=$userIdSource, metadata=${data.metadata}}]")
            gridFS.save(enumerator, data).map {
              image => Some(image)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } yield updateResult

    futureUpdate.flatMap {
      case _ =>  //Some(_)

        val img = Image(BSONObjectID(userIdSource), DateTime.now(), None)
       //  insert the user
        val futureResult2 = snapsCollection.insert(img)
     //    when the insert is performed, send a OK 200 result
        futureResult2.map(_ => Ok("saved"))
    }.recover {
      case e => InternalServerError(e.getMessage())
    }
  }
```

This code takes an image from a form and stores it twice in Mongo DB Grid FS:

- Original image
- Thumb Image

I would like to store in the "img" object 2 additional parameters:

- The id of the original image - it is stored in "file.id"
- The id of the thumb image - It is stored in "image.id"

How can I pass these 2 values to the: "futureUpdate.flatMap"?

Answer (score 3):

Change your yield statement to a tuple `(updateResult, file.id, image.id)`  Then extract them in the pattern match for futureUpdate.flatMap.

Comment: Thanks Gangstead. I am not so familiar with Scala. Can you please show me how to put the tuple in the code?

Comment: OK, I got how to do it for "file.id". How can I add the "image.id" to the tuple? It is not defined in that scope...

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what this code does, but it looks like the type of updateResult is `Future[Unit]` since the last statement it executes is an assignment to `iterator`.  If you change it so that updateResult contains the image.id then you'll be able to access the image.id to add it to the tuple.

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get how to do it. Here is an explanation of what the code does: gridFS.files.update put in mongodb the uploaded image. Then I want to create a thumb from the uploaded image and put it in the mongodb as well. I copied this code from somewhere an it works fine. The "gridFS.enumerate(file)" creates iterator over the file.  The "Enumerator.outputStream" creates the thumb. The "val data = DefaultFileToSave" creates the thumb instance. The "gridFS.save(enumerator, data).map" does the actual db storage. I hope it helps in something...